# <p:calendar. On locale change selected date pattern doesn't change

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

After calendar value is selected I get selected date in the current locale format, then I change locale but selected date value format remains the same and is based on the previous locale.

```
<p:calendar id="tl" locale="#{sessionMngr.locale}"/>
```

When locale is changed all translations are changed accordingly, however date format doens't change.

**[Solved]**

Edit ------------------------------------------------

I got answer from the official primefaces forum

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34013

So basically I just fully update page: window.location.reload(true);

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{mngr.doChangeLocale}" oncomplete="window.location.reload(true);"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain how are you updating your locale?

Comment: Please don't post answer as edit to the question.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [wiki post](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales) regarding PrimeFaces's locale for `<p:calendar>` and `<p:schedule>`. Basically, you need to include the localized labels in the master template so that PrimeFaces can use them to display correctly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But it's not about displaying translations, it's about displaying the right pattern of the date after the date's been selected and locale changed. What I wanted to ask is how can I update date pattern. If I change locale and try to pick date, I get right results, but if I at first pick the date, then change locale, then the date pattern doesn't get updated, even though the calendar itself receives the locale update.